# How to make my website be the first one to appear on Google search?

Tags: google-analytics, web, search-engine

I recently made a website and I already have the server and domain. Now I would like to know how can I make my website be the first one listed in a search?

Could I do it with Google analytics?

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged this with google-chrome? The browser used makes no difference in the context of your question.

Comment: There are entire college courses and countless books on this very topic.  There is no simple answer (or else "everyone" would be #1 on Google!).  You have a lot of research ahead of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics counts and analyses your hits, and helps you see which bits of your site are more popular than others, but it can't make the hits happen in the first place. Google Search Console is the tool for that. But there is no silver bullet, you are going to have to read up on this, and then work at it, a lot over a long time. The real key is having something to sell that others don't, and being easy to do business with so that you get completed sales and repeat customers - i.e. the same rules as have always applied.